# Exception WebClientRequestException not handling by onErrorResume

Tags: exception, spring-webflux, reactive

I wanna check that my server is ready to working with client. For doing this I created post-request, which just send request and if it success, then client-app can changing scene to authorization.

But when I'm trying to handle WebClientRequestException (for case when server is offline but client wanna use application) the onErrorResume method just ignored exception and I get it from stacktrace.

```
    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        startButton.setOnAction(
                actionEvent -> {
                        webClient.post()
                                .uri(healthCheckURL)
                                .retrieve()
                                .bodyToMono(Void.class)
                                .doOnSuccess(response -> {
                                    log.info("Server available!");
                                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            setScene(startButton, "Authorization", AuthController.class, fxWeaver);
                                        }
                                    });
                                })
                                .onErrorResume(WebClientRequestException.class, throwable -> {
                                    try {
                                        mailService.sendEmail(emailConfig, throwable);
                                    } catch (MessagingException e) {
                                        log.error("Error while trying to send email to admin [{}]", e);
                                    }
                                    log.error("Server is unavailable [{}]", throwable.getMessage());
                                    return Mono.error(throwable);
                                })
                                .block();
                });
    }
}
```

**STACKTRACE**

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:10120; nested exception is io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:10120
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)
    Suppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST healthCheckURL [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:55)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:204)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.whenError(FluxRetryWhen.java:225)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:274)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:414)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:251)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:491)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(EmitterProcessor.java:299)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:100)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:190)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:194)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect$ClientTransportSubscriber.onError(HttpClientConnect.java:304)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:194)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onError(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:172)
        at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.fail(AbstractPool.java:477)
        at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.lambda$drainLoop$9(SimpleDequePool.java:401)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(FluxDoOnEach.java:186)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:194)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator$PooledConnectionInitializer.onError(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:554)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:192)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:259)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
        at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector$MonoChannelPromise.tryFailure(TransportConnector.java:517)
        at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector$MonoChannelPromise.setFailure(TransportConnector.java:471)
        at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector.lambda$doConnect$7(TransportConnector.java:206)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:321)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:337)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:707)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1707)
        at ru.bookshelf.client.frontend.StartController.lambda$initialize$2(StartController.java:96)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8886)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3856)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1851)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2584)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:10120
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:660)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:875)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:707)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Process finished with exit code 130
```

Comment: Return a `Mono.empty()` inside the `onErrorResume` lambda to swallow the exception. Returning `Mono.error` there is like rethrowing the exception.